# Project segregation in Sonar Qube

Tags: java, sonarqube, code-separation

I have a projects structure like as shown below.

[image]

**Cloud projects** folder are having four type projects (**eco-projects, evn-projects, met-projects, svn-projects**)

Each type of projects contains again four different projects, like for example in **eco-projects** we have **eco-1-projects, eco-2-projects, eco-3-projects,eco-4-projects**.

I have integrated this in Sonar Qube which I got only one Project as **Cloud projects** like as shown below, when shows all the combined projects source code.

[image]

Can we have a hierarchy like visualization in Sonar Qube, like for example lets say when I click the **Cloud Projects** in Sonar Dashbaord, It will navigate to another four project such as **eco-projects, evn-projects, met-projects, svn-projects** and now lets say when I click **eco-projects** it will show me **eco-1-projects, eco-2-projects, eco-3-projects,eco-4-projects** and now when I click **eco-1-projects** it will show its source code related dashboard and coverages

My **sonar-project.properties** is given below

```
# Required metadata
sonar.projectKey=cloud-projects
sonar.projectName=Cloud Projects
sonar.projectVersion=1.0
# Language
sonar.language=java

# Encoding of the source files
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8

sonar.modules=eco-projects, evn-projects, met-projects, svn-projects

eco-projects.sonar.projectName=eco-projects
eco-projects.sonar.language=java
eco-projects.sonar.modules=eco-1-projects, eco-2-projects, eco-3-projects,eco-4-projects

eco-projects.eco-1-projects.sonar.projectName=eco-1-projects
eco-projects.eco-1-projects.sonar.sources=docroot/WEB-INF/src
eco-projects.eco-1-projects.sonar.language=java

eco-projects.eco-2-projects.sonar.projectName=eco-2-projects
eco-projects.eco-2-projects.sonar.sources=docroot/WEB-INF/src
eco-projects.eco-2-projects.sonar.language=java

eco-projects.eco-3-projects.sonar.projectName=eco-3-projects
eco-projects.eco-3-projects.sonar.sources=docroot/WEB-INF/src
eco-projects.eco-3-projects.sonar.language=java

eco-projects.eco-4-projects.sonar.projectName=eco-4-projects
eco-projects.eco-4-projects.sonar.sources=docroot/WEB-INF/src
eco-projects.eco-4-projects.sonar.language=java
:
:
:
```

Can anyone please tell me some solution for this

Comment: Is connecting to the SonarQube database directly and creating your own HTML/JavaScript page a possible part of the solution?

Comment: @pyb this question is a poor fit for Software Engineering - it would be quickly voted down and closed over there, see [Where does my tool question go?](http://meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/7253/where-does-my-tool-question-go) Recommended reading: **[What goes on Software Engineering (previously known as Programmers)? A guide for Stack Overflow](http://meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/7182/31260)**

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK Sonar doesn't support something like this. It only supports projects, modules and files. This means that you've added (at least?) 1 extra layer Sonar can't work with.

Perhaps you can skip the top 'cloud-projects' level and create a sonar.properties file for each project type? 
If we take eco-projects as an example, you need to create a sonar.properties file for that and define eco-1-projects, eco-2-projects, etc. as modules. This means that eco-projects is
visible in the Sonar dashboard and if you click on it and go to 'code' you'll see all modules. Click on a module to see the files (assuming that is the file level in your case).

BTW you can also use Sonar Dashboards as an extra layer, for example by adding all eco-projects in 1 dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

In SonarQube's menu you have : "Issues", "Measures", "Code" and "Dashboard".

"Code" is the one you want. There, you will find a breakdown by "component" (= one for each of your subprojects).
Each line starts with a small icon (a box with an arrow going out of it, with a tooltip saying : "Open component's page"). This will restrict SQ's scope to this specific component.

Try it out here for example : https://sonarqube.com/code?id=org.apache.hbase%3Ahbase